# Save to Android Pay: how to generate 2 unique ID's per object

Tags: android, google-api, jwt, android-pay

I'm a real rookie with Android and especially 'Save to Android Pay' API. I'm following the [Google's Guide](https://developers.google.com/save-to-android-pay/guides/offers/get-started) and [Google's Sample](https://developers.google.com/save-to-android-pay/samples/quickstart-java), in order to implement my own offer class and "Save to Android" button.

According to the tutorial, for every type of offer card I'm creating, I need one Offer Class, and for every user who will save the card to his Android Pay app, a new object will be generated. So Let's say my card has the following fields:

1. Headline
2. Logo
3. Card ID#

and in addition, every user has 2 unique fields:

4. User ID#
5. User ID2#

I know when and how to pass the first 3 fields of data but I'm not sure where and how to pass the last 2 fields. I'm implementing the "Save to Android" button on a website (exactly like [the sample](https://github.com/android-pay/s2ap-quickstart-java)) and assume I have the two data fields save as JavaScript variables on my website. Can I send the 2 unique fields to **"Save to Android Pay" API Servers** from my website while (or before) the user clicks the "Save to Android Pay" button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer from 'Save to Android Pay' team:

There is a section in the `Loyalty.java` class that creates an object with specified parameters. The Java quickstart has hard-coded values as an example, but can be easily changed to the variables you use to keep track of user's ID numbers, etc.

You can can insert your user's unique values in this section:

```
// Define Wallet Instance
LoyaltyObject object = new LoyaltyObject()
.setClassId(issuerId + "." + classId).setId(issuerId + "." + (Math.random()*1000))
.setState("active").setVersion(1L).setBarcode(barcode).setInfoModuleData(infoModuleData)
.setAccountName("Jane Doe").setTextModulesData(textModulesData)
.setMessages(messages).setLinksModuleData(linksModuleData)
.setAccountId("1234567890").setLoyaltyPoints(points);
```

Also note that in the `WobGenerateJwtServlet.java` class, it creates a JWT depending on the object type.  Specifically for loyalty objects here:

```
// Create the appropriate Object/Classes
if (type.equals("loyalty")) {
  LoyaltyObject obj = Loyalty.generateLoyaltyObject(credentials.getIssuerId(),
      context.getInitParameter("LoyaltyClassId"), context.getInitParameter("LoyaltyObjectId"));

  obj.setFactory(new GsonFactory());
  payload.addObject(obj);
```

Comment: Do you have any sample where you are implementing SDK android mobile app? or Any hint how can we do it in mobile ? e.g. i want Save to Android pay button in activity and all its features.